# Code a tensor view layer in nn.sequential

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I have a `sequential` container and inside I want to use the `Tensor.view` function. Thus my current solution looks like this:

```
class Reshape(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()
        self.my_shape = args

    def forward(self, x):
        return x.view(self.my_shape)
```

and in my `AutoEncoder` class I have:

```
self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
                torch.nn.Linear(self.bottleneck_size, 4096*2),
                Reshape(-1, 128, 8, 8),
                
                nn.UpsamplingNearest2d(scale_factor=2), 
                ...
```

Is there a way to reshape the tensor directly in the `sequential` block so that I do not need to use the externally created `Reshape` class?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNFLATTEN` layer, from [Pytorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Unflatten.html):

> Unflattens a tensor dim expanding it to a desired shape. For use with Sequential.

So you would have:

```
self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Linear(self.bottleneck_size, 4096*2),
            nn.Unflatten(1, (1, 128, 8, 8)), # The first parameters is the dimension you would like to unflatten, note that dimension 0 is usually your batch size. So here we need dimension 1.
            # These alsos work
            # nn.Unflatten(1, (-1, 128, 8, 8)), 
            # nn.Unflatten(1, (128, 8, 8)),                 nn.UpsamplingNearest2d(scale_factor=2), 
            ...
```

You should also check this discussion on [Pytorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-reshape-layer-in-pytorch/1110/9) if you have not already. Also [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/9ec78dab219b950887bcf5988ced1f3e7229765b/torchvision/models/alexnet.py) is how torchvision models used to be implemented in Pytorch. You can see they have separated `Tensor.view` from rest of `Sequential` modules and applied it in the `forward`. The [current version](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/alexnet.py) of same code now uses `flatten`, which means using `unflatten` is reasonable here.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your response! Would you mind going more in details about the first parameter being `0`? I understand that this argument is the dimension of the input tensor to be unflattened but in this specific case why does it have to be `0` and not for example `none` (as in the `view` we do not need to specify dimension)

Comment: Also when I tried to implement it I get an error saying `RuntimeError: unflatten: Provided sizes [1, 128, 8, 8] don't multiply up to the size of dim 0 (256) in the input tensor`   I tried other dimensions and it always returned error, should I (and if so why)  need to changed the output dimension or what else can be the problem if the `view` functioned worked fine

Comment: @Sam333, Unflatten isn't exactly same as reshaping. Unflatten layer will only reshape one of tensor dimension and expands it to the desired shape. E.g. let's say you have a Tensor with shape (20, 100, 20) and you want it to be in the shape (20, 10, 10, 20). Here you will use `Unflatten(1, (10, 10))` as you want to change the shape of second dimension to `(10, 10)`.

Comment: @Sam333, You're right. That's because the dimension `0` is your batch size, so you should use 1. I have edited the answer. I tested this one and it seems to work fine.